# How do i achieve this page transition effect?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I came across this website recently. http://robinmastromarino.com/

Does any one know how this page transition effect has been achieved?

Answer (score 1):

It is not the css3. Percent animation is a [gif](http://robinmastromarino.com/images/generics/loader.gif). And the page appearance transition is made with sprites([1](http://robinmastromarino.com/images/sprites/sprites-0.png), [2](http://robinmastromarino.com/images/sprites/sprites-1.png), [3](http://robinmastromarino.com/images/sprites/sprites-2.png)) using [pixijs](http://www.pixijs.com/). Here some sprite [demo](http://pixijs.github.io/examples/index.html?s=basics&f=spritesheet.js&title=SpriteSheet%20Animation) by pixi.js